# Windows Easy Transfer hanging

Tags: windows-easy-transfer

I have a Windows Easy Transfer session that constantly says "1 min left".

Can I assume that the backup is quite complete?  How can I get out of it?

I'm backing up to a drive I'm also backing up from, and I think it's far more data than I need (140 GB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long has it been at 1 minute remaining?  Last one I did sat there for what seemed like a long time.  As I was not there when it finished, I am not sure how long in total.

Even with compression, you need space for the transfer file so be sure you have lots of space.

If it failed, check all logs for possible solutions or error.